# Unity How To Get The Camera borders as a vector3?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

i need to get the camera borders as a vector3 to store it and use it later in the game .
as the image show you , i need to get this positions , so whatever camera move anywhere , i can determine the borders of my game.

[image]

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-rect.html  -  Just check out the Camera API

Comment: it is about set the value that i want , But Actually what i need is to get the value of the camera coordinate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Camera.ScreenPointToRay(Vector3 pixelPosition) to get a given ray from the camera that crosses a given pixel coordinate (z position is ignored), than if you multiply by distance (your end plane distance?) you'll get coortinates of your points